# Java upcasting and downcasting by interfaces

Tags: java, interface, upcasting

This is probably a dumb question but I need to know.
I have an interface as

```
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBAsync;

public interface AsyncClient extends AmazonDynamoDBAsync{

}
```

And I have a **ClientCreator** class which has the method

```
import com.company.clients.AsyncClient;
public class ClientCreator {
        public static AsyncClient getAsyncClient() throws FileNotFoundException, IllegalArgumentException, IOException{
            AmazonDynamoDBAsync client = new AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClient(getCredentials());
            client.setRegion(getRegion());
            return (AsyncClient)client;
        }
        .
        .
        .
```

Here **AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClient implements AmazonDynamoDBAsync** and **AsyncClient extends AmazonDynamoDBAsync**, but this code would not work and throws

> com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClient cannot be
>   cast to com.company.clients.AsyncClient

but **why**?

Comment: Does `AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClient` implement `AsyncClient`?

Comment: No it doesn't, and it can't. But it implements AmazonDynamoDBAsync and AsyncClient extends that one.

Comment: So, if `Poodle` implements `Animal` and `Cat` extends `Animal`, you're basically asking, "how do i treat a `Poodle` as a `Cat`?"

Comment: Here's some basic documentation on casting and inheritence in java http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Basically you've got the hierarchy like this:

```
         AmazonDynamoDBAsync 
                  ^
                  |
     -----------------------------
     |                           |
AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClient   AsyncClient
```

And you are trying to cast `AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClient` instance to `AsyncClient`, which isn't possible. Those are siblings. Take it like this: "Apple" and "Banana" are both "Fruit", but an "Apple" is not a "Banana".

Comment: Just logically somehow I feel like I must be able to cast, since Class1 and Interface2 actually shares methods. And casted object would  get only the methods which is available in Interface1. But of course I might be completely wrong at all.

Comment: @ufucuk: You can't cast to something that isn't in the type's lineage, as Rohit points out. That's just fundamental. It doesn't matter how similar they are, they're different things by definition. Assuming `interface Base`, and we have `interface A extends Base` and `interface B extends Base` (neither of which adds anything to `Base`). you can't cast `A` to `B` (or vice-versa). `A` is not in `B`'s lineage, nor vice-versa.

Comment: Ok that seems I have to read all up and down casting stuff again. Thanks.